# How to bind my linux kernel module to InfiniBand HCA ports to send and receive messages via this module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, infiniband

I want my kernel module get bind to an InfiniBand port and in turn register to the subnet administrator for future operations like query, send , receive.

I have searched on the web but unfortunately there is very little info about it.

At present, I'm referring the **IPoIB implementation** but it seems to have lots of structures and funtions which are irrelevant to my kernel module.

So, I'm searching the minimalistic and optimised steps to register my module to the InfiniBand SA.

Comment: There is ib_sa kernel module that you can use as a refference